# My Pandas dataframe column names have prefixes F1_column_name, F2_column_name.. F12_column_name. How can i remove these prefixes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Below is the sample of how my data frame looks like. How can i remove the prefixes.

| pol_num | date | F2_class | F7_ded_amt | F8_terr_cd | F12_Limit_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12nk23k | 20210202 | MS30 | 1000 | Y | 120000 |
| 123jj9k | 20210304 | MS30 | 1022 | Y | 129090 |
| 1232j00j | 20210402 | JK00 | 900 | N | 90009 |

Comment: `df.columns=df.columns.str.split('_').str[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code.  The first argument is the name as it appears now, and then you can write how you want it to appear in the second argument.

```
df = df.rename(columns={'$a':'a'})
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just a quick question. As per your suggestion i need to specify each and every column name manually. can i do it through script? because i dont exactly know the column names. only during the runtime we would know the column names. but we do know that there are prefixes.